# Weired character when using pandas.to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, character-encoding

I'm having an Excel file with some French characters. I'm using the following code to load the file

```
p = pd.read_excel(file_path, encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
```

When I look at the dataframe in python it looks good.

I then want to save it as a csv file with pipe-delimited (|) file. I'm using the code

```
p.to_csv(outputfile,delimeter= '|',encoding = 'utf-8)
```

but after opening the csv file, it contains some weired character. What encoding should I use

Comment: have you tried `p.to_csv(outputfile, sep=b'|', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: correct, I edited my original post

Comment: should I use utf-16?

Comment: Can you post one of these lines containing the French chars?